# Force add new page in pyFPDF using python

Tags: python-2.7, pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf

I'm using pyFPDF templates to generate pdf but I want to print two pages not only one is this possible! 
for example:

```
elements = [
    { 'name': 'company_logo', 'type': 'I', 'x1': 20.0, 'y1': 17.0, 'x2': 78.0, 'y2': 30.0, 'font': None, 'size': 0.0, 'bold': 0, 'italic': 0, 'underline': 0, 'foreground': 0, 'background': 0, 'align': 'I', 'text': 'logo', 'priority': 2, },
    { 'name': 'company_name', 'type': 'T', 'x1': 17.0, 'y1': 32.5, 'x2': 115.0, 'y2': 37.5, 'font': 'Arial', 'size': 12.0, 'bold': 1, 'italic': 0, 'underline': 0, 'foreground': 0, 'background': 0, 'align': 'I', 'text': '', 'priority': 2, },
    { 'name': 'box', 'type': 'B', 'x1': 15.0, 'y1': 15.0, 'x2': 185.0, 'y2': 260.0, 'font': 'Arial', 'size': 0.0, 'bold': 0, 'italic': 0, 'underline': 0, 'foreground': 0, 'background': 0, 'align': 'I', 'text': None, 'priority': 0, },
    { 'name': 'box_x', 'type': 'B', 'x1': 95.0, 'y1': 15.0, 'x2': 105.0, 'y2': 25.0, 'font': 'Arial', 'size': 0.0, 'bold': 1, 'italic': 0, 'underline': 0, 'foreground': 0, 'background': 0, 'align': 'I', 'text': None, 'priority': 2, },
    { 'name': 'line1', 'type': 'L', 'x1': 100.0, 'y1': 25.0, 'x2': 100.0, 'y2': 57.0, 'font': 'Arial', 'size': 0, 'bold': 0, 'italic': 0, 'underline': 0, 'foreground': 0, 'background': 0, 'align': 'I', 'text': None, 'priority': 3, },
]
#here we instantiate the template and define the HEADER
f = Template(format="A4", elements=elements,
             title="Sample Invoice")
f.add_page()
#we FILL some of the fields of the template with the information we want
#note we access the elements treating the template instance as a "dict"
f["company_name"] = "Sample Company"
f["company_logo"] = "pyfpdf/tutorial/logo.png"

#and now we render the page
f.render("./template.pdf")
```

All those data appears in the same pdf when I use this method, I want some of the elements to print on the second page of  pdf? How can I do it , any help?!

Answer (score 1):

You can separate elements in two different lists (elements1, elements2) and use each one in different templates and merge them using [PyPDF2](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2)

```
f1 = Template(format="A4", elements=elements1,
         title="Sample Invoice")

f2 = Template(format="A4", elements=elements2,
         title="Sample Invoice")

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader
from StringIO import StringIO

page1 = StringIO()
page2 = StringIO()
final_pdf = StringIO()

page1.write(f1.render('doc1.pdf',dest='S'))
page2.write(f2.render('doc2.pdf',dest='S'))

pages = [ PdfFileReader(page1), PdfFileReader(page2) ]
pdf_merger = PdfFileMerger()

for page in pages:
    pdf_merger.append(page)

pdf_merger.write(final_pdf)
```

You can get the final output from **final_pdf.getvalue()**.